# MVC4 passing a value to more than one controller at a time from an ActionLink

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Does anynone know if it is possible to pass a value from an action link to more that one controller?

The situation i have is an Index page uses ajax requests to render 3 partial views.
Ive amended the partial views to contain links to a report and in turn would like this to be passed back to the partial views with a refresh of the index page.

As i dont call the partial views the ID is never passed to the partial view.

My action link in my partial view is

```
@Html.ActionLink(@item.Project.ProjectTitle, "../Dashboard/Index", new { id = item.Project.ProjectID })
```

My ajax call to render the partial view is

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Project/ProjectPartial',
    contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'html',
data: {
    documentType: $('#DocumentType').val(),
    sectionName: $('#SectionName').val()
}
})
.success(function (result) {
    // Display the section contents.
    $('#Projects').html(result);
})
.error(function (xhr, status) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
});
```

Ive tried putting in data the attribute id: id, but this does not seem to result in anything.

Comment: Sorry One link will point to only one href resource(controller)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to render a page you should make a 'GET' but you are making the 'POST' Request, change the request Type to 'GET' and try.

```
$.ajax({
url: '/Project/ProjectPartial',
contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'html',
data: {
documentType: $('#DocumentType').val(),
sectionName: $('#SectionName').val()
}
})
.success(function (result) {
// Display the section contents.
$('#Projects').html(result);
})
.error(function (xhr, status) {
alert(xhr.responseText);
});
```

Comment: Ive tried changing it to GET but this has no effect. No id is passed and it returns the same partial view as vefore.